# Send POJO with BigDecimal value returns null

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have a Spring Feign client which is sending POJO object to remote endpoint using POST:

```
SaleRequestFactory obj = new SaleRequestFactory();
        obj.setId(insertedTransaction.getId());
        obj.setAmount(wpfRequestDTO.getAmount());
```

DTO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class SaleRequestFactory implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1744050117179344127L;
    
    private BigDecimal amount;  
}


@FeignClient(name = "remote-service")
public interface NetClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/engine/sale")
    SaleResponseFactory setInitTransaction(SaleRequestFactory saleRequestFactory);
}
```

When I try to get amount I get:

```
nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.math.BigDecimal.doubleValue()" because the return value of "org.SaleRequestFactory.getAmount()" is null] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.math.BigDecimal.doubleValue()" because the return value of "org.SaleRequestFactory.getAmount()" is null
```

Is it possible that Spring is not properly converting `BigDecimal` when there is POST request received?
Do I need to convert the value into `Integer` in order to read properly the number?

Comment: What `BigDecimal` value did you send? Stacktrace said that is your value is null. Try to add `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` on `BigDecimal` field.

Comment: Could you please update your question and show us the request you are sending? Further where is `java.math.BigDecimal.doubleValue()` invoked?